# Tree Traversal, generate a linkedlist from tree preorder and write test case for it

Tags: linked-list, automated-tests, binary-tree

I am looking for best solutions for the following question.

We are given a binary tree, we need to generate a linked list from the tree using pre order traversal. Also write a test case to check whether its correct.

If you can provide a solution specific to a generating linked list and testing. Also what would be best complexity that can be achieved for this solution.

I have tried something like this :

```
public void TraversePreOrder(TreeNode node, LinkedListNode head){

    if(node != null) return;

    //Insert current node into linkedList 
    head = insertNodeIntoLinkedList(head, node.data);
    PreOrder(node.left, head);
    PreOrder(node.right, head);
}


public LinkedListNode insertNodeIntoLinkedList(LinkedListNode head, int data){

    LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(data);
    if(head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        return head;
    }

    Node currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode.next != null){
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    currentNode.next = newNode;
    return head;

}
```

Comment: I have added code, i am not sure what whether i could better and also wanted to check Test Cases for it

Comment: Pre-order traversal always goes through the whole tree. Unless you do something funny, it is always going to be O(n) where n is the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in any traversal order we print the data from the node that we come across on the screen. However, you can easily replace the print function with an insert function.

Create a linked list and a function to insert data in your linked list. Then create your tree, input data from it from the user (if that is what you want) then create a function for preorder traversel and instead of printing the date on the screen you can add it to your linked list.